# Right key invisible on a UItablewView... into Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, rightbarbuttonitem

If it was a problem of code, seems to need a clean!!!
I however have made all clean procedure, but the problem is there...
The problem: I have added a right button (Tab Bar button) to a top Bar.
The left (back) goes perfect, but I cannot view the right button... He disappear when I make a build and execute the app!!!
Some idea?

Ps. In other UITableView of the project I have normally two buttons.

Comment: Are you adding it programatically or in storyboard? check if the hidden property is YES?

Comment: In storyboard.... and hidden is not checked :(
But however when you add bar button item you don't have hidden property like a normal button under Attributes inspector...

Comment: try to clean the project and run again

Comment: I've done hundred times.... I've also deleted the app from devices (Virtual and real) but nothing.... Is so strange!

Comment: You are trying to add the UIBarButtonItem to the NavigationController right, check tintColor and barTintColor properties of barButton and NavigationBar, or alternatively try adding the BarButtonItem programatically in viewDidLoad and check if it's visible.

Comment: The colors are ok... (in fact I can see the left button).
Last chance is to do all programmatically!!!
I will update you. Thanks for now.

Comment: ..after thousand and thousand of "clean" and  "mac restart", Ladies and gentlemen, the right button is here!!!! Yheeeaaaa!!!

What will be happened? I don't care.... Now works and this is enough
 
Thanks Suhit and sorry for the stolen time.